# Suggest an alternative to "re-enable"?

Tags: synonyms

First time I've asked on this Stack; I hope this is on-topic.

I'm laying out a control panel. One of its functions involves an alarm, but under certain circumstances the alarm might be triggered repeatedly, which is annoying. So there's a button which prevents the alarm happening for a while, which is labelled "[problem] Alarm Silence" - not entirely grammatical, but I'm happy with it in context.

The alarm warns of a potentially expensive mistake, so you don't want to accidentally leave it silenced. So you should manually press this button again when silencing is no longer really necessary, and the control system will also do that for you if it notices you leaving the specific situation that causes multiple alarms. And in any case after a certain length of time.

Underneath the button is an explanatory note which currently says:

> Silenced when lit.
>
> Press to re-enable.
>
> Also re-enables automatically.

I think that's clear, but I don't really like the word "re-enable". Can anyone suggest a good alternative, bearing in mind the limited space available on the physical panel? All the replacements I can think of - "activate", for example - imply that they will immediately sound the alarm. That's not what happens; re-enabling just allows the alarm to go off if it wants to, it doesn't actively cause it to sound.

Comment: Perhaps *reactivates*? And you can call the silencing *deactivates*.

Comment: Disabled when lit.  Press to enable.  (“re-enable” assumes smething about its prior state- no such assumption is required.)

Comment: Like the surge protector on a power strip, you'd "reset" the button.

Comment: Mash button. See what happens.  Actually, I like "reset". +1.

Comment: This situation seems to be analogous to a car, where, if you have put the transmission into neutral, you can rev the engine all you want without any energy or force being applied to the wheels.  The operation you're describing corresponds to putting the car back into gear, so, the next time you step on the gas, the car will accelerate.  For some reason the word *engage* springs to my mind; perhaps this analogy will inspire you to think of other words.

Answer (score 3):

How about *press to [**arm**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arm+the+alarm%2Calarm+is+armed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carm%20the%20alarm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calarm%20is%20armed%3B%2Cc0)*?

> To prepare (a weapon or electronic system, such as an alarm) for use or operation, as by releasing a safety device. [FOD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/arm)

Answer (score 3):

Just **enable**. No **re** is needed. It's the status, not the history that you want to convey.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "press to enable sound".

It's probably longer than what you had in mind, but it really is the clearest option.

Answer (score 0):

I would employ the verb **restore,** or possibly even **reinstate,** in this context.

> ```
> Silenced when lit.
>
> Press to restore.
>
> Also reinstates automatically.
> ```